# how to parse data from local JSON file and save in a model class and use in tableview

Tags: json, swift

i want to parse JSON from local JSON file and want to save that data in a model class and the show it on tableview. how i can parse JSON from local file.

here is my JSON file-- JsonFile.json

```
{
"teams":[
         {
         "teamName":"Arsenal",
         "image":"Arsenal",
         "nextMatch":"in 2 days",
         "matches":[
                    {
                    "oppositeTeam":"teamName",
                    "matchTimings":"121212",
                    "matchId":"ID 213432"
                    },
                    {
                    "oppositeTeam":"teamName",
                    "matchTimings":"121212",
                    "matchId":"ID 213432"
                    }
                    ],
         "fixtures":{
         "oppositeTeam":"teamName",
         "oppositeTeamScore":"7",
         "homeTeamScore":"4",
         "homeTeamCards":"True",
         "oppositeTeamCards":"false",
         "fixtureId":"ID 213432"
         }
         },
         {
         "teamName":"Chelsea",
         "image":"Chelsea",
         "nextMatch":"in 2 days",
         "matches":{
         "oppositeTeam":"teamName",
         "matchTimings":"121212",
         "matchId":"ID 213432"
         },
         "fixtures":{
         "oppositeTeam":"teamName",
         "oppositeTeamScore":"7",
         "homeTeamScore":"4",
         "homeTeamCards":"True",
         "oppositeTeamCards":"false",
         "fixtureId":"ID 213432"
         }
         },
         {
         "teamName":"India",
         "image":"India",
         "nextMatch":"in 2 days"
         }
         ]
```

}

here is my model class where i wan to store data from JSON file.

```
   class TeamData : Decodable{
let teamName : String
let image : String
let nextMatch : String?
let matches : [Match]
let fixtures : [Fixture]
```

}

```
class Match : Decodable{
let oppositeTeam : String?
let matchTimings : String?
let matchId : String?
```

}

```
class Fixture : Decodable{
let oppositeTeam : String?
let oppositeTeamScore : String?
let HomeTeamScore : String?
let HomeTeamCards : String?
let oppositeTeamCards : String?
let fixtureId : String?
```

}

now how to parse data from JSON file and save it on model class.. i have seen a lots of tutorials but every one is using API so its really confusing how to parse  JSON from local file

Comment: The JSON data is inconsistent. `matches` is once array and once dictionary which makes the decoding process expensive. As the file is local I recommend to change the JSON to consolidate the types. By the way `fixtures` is a dictionary (note the `{}`) not array. And don't ignore the root object, the dictionary with key `teams`.

Comment: Ok, I edited my answer. Now it should work correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Fix your json struct and class for TeamData**

Change your TeamData class to match with your json

```
class TeamData: Decodable {
    var teamName : String
    var image : String
    var nextMatch : String?
    var matches : [Match]?
    var fixtures : Fixtures?
}
```

for team Chelsea you forget to put match to array, so fix it like this:

```
[{
     "oppositeTeam":"teamName",
     "matchTimings":"121212",
     "matchId":"ID 213432"
}]
```

I think, the best would be if only thing in your json file was array of TeamData objects. So, delete

```
{ “teams”:
```

and `}` in the end and keep just array of teams

**How to get json from json file**

Somewhere in your ViewController create empty array of TeamData

```
 var teams = [TeamData]()
```

Now get reference to your json file, try to create Data from it and decode this data it using JSONDecoder

```
let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "JsonFile", withExtension: "json")!
do {
    let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
    teams = JSONDecoder().decode([TeamData].self, from: data)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

I also recommend you to rename your file to **Teams.json**

*also don’t forget rename it in line where you’re getting URL of your file*

Comment: Basically you are right but this will cause a *Expected to decode Array<Any> but found a dictionary instead* error.

Comment: It still doesn't work but the errors are not related to your answer. There are a few wrong types in the structs.

Comment: @vadian Ok, now I also solved problém with wrong types in the structs

Comment: how we can fetch "matchId" @RobertDresler

Comment: @harinderrana replace “matchId”:”ID 213432” with “matchId”:213432 (don’t forget to replace it like this everywhere in your json struct) and in Match class replace var matchId: String? with var matchId: Int? when you want to get for Example matchId of first match for Arsenal, in your code use teams[0].matches[0].matchId!

Comment: @RobertDresler i am not able to access "matchId" , "matchTimings","oppositeTeam" from matches in viewcontroller. using teams[0].matches[0].matchId!. but i have accessed data in teams[0]

Comment: @harinderrana I’m sorry, try this: teams[0].matches[0]!.matchId!