# Getting Specific Value From Json Response For View Controller

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire

I'm making my request with Alamofire and I have a class to show some value. I want to show the value in interface.

here's my code :

```
class API: NSObject {

   class func group1(groupid: Int) {


        Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: headers)
            .responseJSON { response in

                switch response.result {

                case .success(let data):
                    let json = JSON(data)
                    //print(json)

                    let ds_valIntake1 = json["data"][0]["ds_val"].int
                    let ds_valIntake1Sig = json["data"][1]["ds_val"].int
                    let ds_valLevel = json["data"][2]["ds_val"].int

                }
        }

    }
}
```

I want to get the value from those "ds_val" then show its value into interface. I don't want to use userdefaults to move those value into another class.

Comment: go through https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53278297/how-to-parse-data-from-local-json-file-and-save-in-a-model-class-and-use-in-tabl

Comment: and you call this group1 method from the Interface(ViewController) right?

Comment: here's a good tutorial to follow --> https://www.raywenderlich.com/35-alamofire-tutorial-getting-started
and this one is bit advance  -->> https://medium.com/@AladinWay/write-a-networking-layer-in-swift-4-using-alamofire-and-codable-part-1-api-router-349699a47569

Answer (score 0):

- use the below

```
import Foundation

class ResponseModel: Codable {

    var data: [DataModel]?

    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case data = "data"
    }

}

class DataModel: Codable {

    var ds_val: Int?

    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case ds_val = "ds_val"
    }

}

func buildObjectFromResponse(data: Data?) -> ResponseModel? {
    var object : ResponseModel?
    do {
        object = try JSONDecoder().decode(ResponseModel.self , from: data!)
    } catch (let error){
        print(error)
    }
    return object
}
```

```
class API: NSObject {

    class func group1(groupid: Int) {


        Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: headers)
            .responseJSON { response in

                switch response.result {

                case .success(let data):

                    if let response = buildObjectFromResponse(data: data){
                         /* save things to UserDefaults here */
                    }

                }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just create a `Codable` class with the exact format of your **response**? Then you can use `JSONSerialization` to get the data into a codable object, and then pass that back in a completion block.

Create a codable class:

```
    class Response: Codable { 
                //Populate this with all the fields you need
     }
```

and then in your Alamofire call you could write:

```
class API {

           func group1(groupid: Int, onSuccess: @escaping Response) {


                Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: headers)
                    .responseJSON { response in

                        switch response.result {

                        case .success(let data):
                        if let data = JSONDecoder.decode(Response.self, from: responseObject) {
                              onSuccess(data)
                          }

                        }
                }

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use completion blocks, Apple created that one for these kind of purposes

```
static func group1(groupid: Int, completion:@escaping (_ r:Any) -> Void) -> Void
    {

    Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: headers)
        .responseJSON { response in

            switch response.result {

            case .success(let data):
                let json = JSON(data)
                //print(json)
                  completion(json as Any}


            }
    }
}
```

And call

```
 className.group1(groupid: Int, completion: { (jsonResult) in
          let json = jsonResult as yourType
          let ds_valIntake1 = json["data"][0]["ds_val"].int
          let ds_valIntake1Sig = json["data"][1]["ds_val"].int
          let ds_valLevel = json["data"][2]["ds_val"].int
        })
```